# Whether my private date could be saved when process killed my activity in android?

Tags: android, process

I have to give a dialog when my activity is launched at first time.
So I do that in my

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

and use

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
```

to save the time of my launch. I notice that OS create a new "Bundle outState" instead of using the old one. And I can not debug the the date when re Oncreate.

My question:

1. The date I saved in onSaveInstanceState , could be really read by Oncreate? And how to debug?
2. Could I just use a private member vary to save the state and without being deleted by OS when the process is killed by OS.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I test the onSaveInstanceState , the date doesn't be saved. I have to use static to handle that. But I Found the static don't be initiated when I relaunch my app. I have to kill it in OnDestroy. How stupid android is!!

Comment: How stupid Android is?  I think you'll find that the problem is not with Android!  When you say "I test the onSaveInstanceState, the date doesn't be saved", what do you mean?  I use onSaveInstance a lot and it works fine.  How are you storing the date to the bundle?  Please show the code.  And I'm sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about with the static and "I have to kill it in OnDestroy".  Kill what?  The static?  There is no requirement to use statics in onSaveInstance.

Comment: And to debug your date in onCreate, why not assign the value to whatever field you are holding it in then write the value to logcat?

Comment: my code:@Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if( sp.getBoolean(SP_AGREEMENT, false) == true ){
   mb_isMenuActiveOnPause = true;
   outState.putBoolean(MENU_ACTIVE_ONPAUSE_COUNTER, mb_isMenuActiveOnPause);
        }
 }

Comment: And I get the value in Oncreate like this:  if (savedInstanceState != null){
   mb_isMenuActiveOnPause = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(MENU_ACTIVE_ONPAUSE_COUNTER, false);
  }

Comment: About static, I have a static data. And I initialize it as "false", set it to "true" in  onSaveInstanceState, and just shutdown my app, and launch it again, I got "true" from Oncreate.....I have no idea. I have to set it to "false" at Ondestroy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bundle` cannot be used to carry the data across application restarts.

You'd better save your data to the more permanent storage, like `SharedPreferences`, put this code in `onCreate()`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs = getSharedPreferences( "preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
long last_run_time = prefs.getLong( 'last_run', 0 );
if( last_run_time == 0 ) { // zero means your app has never been run
    // display dialog, this is the first time!
    ....
    // this saves current system time to prevent your dialog being seen again
    prefs.edit().putLong( 'last_run', system.currentTimeMillis() ).commit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. But I want to display some dialog when it Oncreate at first time, not all times. You know my activity may be killed by OS, and if I only save my data in Onpause using SharedPreferences, it can not know whether it is the first or second time.

Comment: please, see the revised version, i've added the possible way to check when to display a dialog or not. also, you don't have to save exact running time, just save a boolean to preferences when your dialog is displayed. the main point of my answer is, don't use `savedInstanceState` for the values which should live for a long time.

Comment: Thank you. You are so nice. Maybe I'm not very clearly. I have to put "app stopped abnormally last time" if it stopped abnormally. Now I tried onSaveInstanceState again, it works fine until now. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you guys, I think I know where I was wrong, I have to save my data every times at onSaveInstanceState , and it could only be used by one time in Oncreate. Thank you all.

Comment: Amy,you should be more clear not about the topic at hand (saving data in `onSaveInstance()`), but about the goal you're trying to achieve. Because most of the time you actually need to achieve a different goal, or achieve it in a different way. In Android, 'stopped abnormally' means "force closed", and when the system removes your inactive app from the memory -- it's not abnormal, it's intended behaviour you should not worry about.